# Unable to install rails. error: You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3 directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, rvmrc

I installed  ruby 2.6.3 using RVM. later when i try to install rails i am getting following error.

$ gem install rails -v 6.0.2.1

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3 directory.

$ sudo gem install rails -v 6.0.2.1

sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/gem: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because at some point you used `sudo` to install your rvm. So, the system will require `sudo` permission to install later gems

When you use command `$ sudo gem install rails -v 6.0.2.1`, you tell system to use normal directly installed ruby, not via `rvm`, so it warns you `No such /user/bin/gem` error

The solution for this is to change ownership of all files in the `~/.rvm` directory to current account, as if you're using `root` account by following command

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.rvm
```

Comment: Thanks.. instead of sudo, can i use rvmsudo?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `rvmsudo` however, you can try. I think it can work

Comment: **chown: /Users/igorganapolsky/.rvm: No such file or directory**